# Finding distribution and expectation of $Z_1=\max(1,X_1,X_2)$ and $Z_2=\min(2,X_1,X_2)$

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Find distribution and expectation of $Z_1=\max(1,X_1,X_2)$ and $Z_2=\min(2,X_1,X_2)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have distribution function
$$F(x) = 1 - e^{-x}.\quad x\ge0$$

My thoughts: For $Z_1 = \min(2,X_1,X_2)$,
\begin{align*}
F_{Z_1}(x) &= P(Z_1 \le x) = 1 - P(Z_1 > x) = 1 - P(\min(2, X_1,X_2)\gt x)\\
&= 1 - P(2 > x)P(X_1>x)P(X_2>x)\\
&= \begin{cases}1 - e^{-2x}, 0<x\le2\\0, x>2\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and $E[Z_1] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x·2e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$ as I understand. For $Z_2 = \max(1,X_1,X_2)$,
\begin{align*}
F_{Z_2}(x) &= P(Z_2 \le x) = P(\max(1, X_1,X_2)\le x)\\
&= P(1 \le x)P(X_1\le x)P(X_2\le x)\\
&= \begin{cases}1 - e^{-2x}, x>1\\0, 0<x\le1\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and $E[Z_2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x·2e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$.

Am I right with my assumtions?

Comment: We have $F_{Z_1}(2)=P(Z_1\le 2)=1$ but the formula you found does not match.

Comment: you've made some silly mistakes.

 1. $P(2>2)=0$
 2. $P(1\leq 1)=1$